# ExpressJs route not detecting properly

Tags: express

I've the following routes defined, I don't understand why express is trying to use the first route and throwing cast error when I call the second route. sub is not a route param, but still it is consider so.

app.get('/api/main/:id', requestId, abcController.findOne);

app.get('/api/main/sub', requestId, abcController.findAll);

Comment: Express uses the first route because it's declared first and it _also_ matches `/api/main/sub`.

Comment: thanks robert, do you know what is the workaround for this situation without the need to change the route.

Comment: Turn their declaration around (`/api/main/sub` first, `/api/main/:id` next).

Comment: will that not be a problem when I wanted to call /api/main/:id with a query param. I'm trying this now though

Comment: It will only be a problem if that parameter equals `sub` (which, I would think, won't happen).

Comment: Thanks you so much. It worked.